# Multiply pd.Dataframe's specific cells by the python list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Imagine we have dataframe and let's try to filter it like:

```
df[df[0] == 'Test_value'].iloc[:, 1:5]
```

So that we have filtered by values `Test_value` in a column `0`, and we take only 1 to 5 columns. Now I want to change these values from dataframe. I want to multiply them by a list like [1,3,1,2].

At the end, I want my initial dataframe with changes only in those specific cells.

ps: `df.mul()` func doing well but it's only return me changed cells `(df[df[0] == 'Test_value].iloc[:, 1:5])`, but I cannot set them to my initial dataframe: `df[df[0] == 'Test_value].iloc[:, 1:5] = df[df[0] == 'Test_value].iloc[:, 1:5].mul(list)` not working ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with chain indexing, possible solution is filter by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) only with convert boolean mask to numpy array by [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        0:['Test_value'] *6,
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
})

dont use variable list because builtins
L = [1,3,1,2]
#pandas 0.24+
df.iloc[(df[0] == 'Test_value').to_numpy(), 1:5] *= L
#pandas below
#df.iloc[(df[0] == 'Test_value').values, 1:5] *= L
print (df)

            0  B   C  D   E  F
0  Test_value  4  21  1  10  5
1  Test_value  5  24  3   6  3
2  Test_value  4  27  5  12  6
3  Test_value  5  12  7  18  9
4  Test_value  5   6  1   4  2
5  Test_value  4   9  0   8  4
```

Comment: it's strange but I have issue with Series method "to_numpy()".

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов - Be free change it to `.values`

Comment: Your solution is great! Thank you. Can you please say a few words about why my approach doesn't work?

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов - I think it is same principe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316) - only instaed `iloc[:, 1:5]` is there used `['B']`